# Keep pageranks switching to Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, web, dns, pagerank

We are doing real good in Google search results and have a high pagerank with our HTML webpage (several pages like 30).

Now we are switching to a Wordpress website on the same domain, and are keeping most of the HTML-pages. But we also are building another Wordpress page on a NEW Domain, here we will showcase the hardware products (we are now showing at our existing domain with HTML).

How could we safely switch one half of HTML-page to Wordpress )on same domain) and keep pagerank, and move the other HTML-page to a Wordpress page on a NEW Domain and keep the pagerank?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this [tutorial](http://rtcamp.com/blogger-to-wordpress/tutorials/permalink-seo-migration/). It's not quite the same, but it's going to talk you through the important parts of a transfer to minimize loss of SEO.

Basically make sure you keep all the current links to your pages working after the transfer.

> 1. Import all posts, comments & pages.
> 2. Maintaining permalinks for posts & pages (1-on-1 mapping between Blogger.com and WordPress pages).
> 3. Redirecting permalinks for labels & search archives.
> 4. Retaining all feed subscribers.